# Cho'gath AP/AD Hybrid Build?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm fairly new to league. I started playing with Warwick and really enjoyed him, but I got bored of him very quickly. I enjoy fairly high health, strong, carry champions with good CC and high kill farm and champion kill rates. I've recently been playing Cho'gath and been thoroughly enjoying it.

I've been building him as a pure AP carry.  I get items such as abyssal scepter, rod of ages, Rabadon's Deathcap, etc.  I sometimes swap out the abyssal with a magic resist or high armour item based on situation. This gives me tons of AP and therefore my vorpal spikes does a lot of damage.

However, I also realized Cho has one of the highest AD stats in the game at level 18. Therefore I was wondering if it was worth doing an AD/AP hybrid build on him.  He already gets tons of health from feast so is naturally fairly tanky and hard to kill. Does anyone have experience playing Cho this way? Or do you guys have any recommendations on good AD items to get to go with my current AP build?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am thoroughly enjoying the game and playing with Cho! Also if you guys have any tips on fun champions to try based on what I've described that would be awesome too! Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately builds for champions are very time sensitive as items/champs change. I'd say you should check out http://leaguecraft.com/ or http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/chogath-guide or http://www.lolpro.com/guides/chogath/88-chogath-build-guide-top-lane-by-pobelter-and or http://www.solomid.net/guides.php?g=740-westrice-chogath-build-guide all of these sites provide updated builds for champions. This site is more for providing answers to things that don't change frequently.

Comment: if your looking for help creating weird builds im always happy to help. I thrive on builds no one uses.

Answer (score 2):

In reality you can play any champion AD, ( for example i've ADC'd as ahri back when you could still random pick after the client crashed.) AD being Attack Damage is usually just based off of entirely basic attack damage. Unless of course your trying to be an AD caster which would require a high AD ratio for your spells which Cho'gath obviously doesnt have. So in other words yes you can be Chog'ath AD having a silence and knockup with a little extra AOE and a painful true damage ult, you could easily close the gap on a normal ranged ADC, if you go bottom lane try having a support that has a stun or root of sorts. Just build pure AD/AS, Berserker boots, Ifinity Edge, Bloodthirst, Phantom Dancer, etc. Might wanna rush Frozen mallet for the slow, so when you get them close they can't get away easily.

If your hell bent on trying to use Cho with AD try going more Hybrid, so items like rageblade, hextech, and trinity force.

The real trick is actually getting fed fast enough to beat a champion who is built more for AD. I would max  Cho's AOE attack first to get all the CS I could and try to force him under his turret to starve him, and you'll need to ward well if you plan on keeping him under his tower. And if it fails expect harrassment for being a troll, being this would be considered a troll build.

Comment: I think I'll look into those hybrid items. I def agree building AP Cho gives a HUGE advantage, but I've always wanted to try giving him some AD. Some of those items look awesome so I'll try putting them into my build! thanks!

Comment: Yah hybrid will give cho a lot of sustain, specially if you build those with some tanky items. I could see him being very strong.

Comment: +1 guinsoo rageblade and you could also couple it with wit's end wich will give you more MR and lowering the enemy's + on hit effect and the AS inscreasing vorpal frequence .. just amazing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In general hybrid builds often sucks.

**Cho'gath** has very high [AP ratios](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Cho%27Gath) (this means that he scales well with lots of AP) and investing money in AD items are wasting his superior AP/Tank potential.

Here you have table with **how much DPS AP hero can deal** and Cho is at **6th place**! This is to damn high :) [source in Polish here](http://how2play.pl/przeliczniki-ap-pod-lupa/).

[image: For more info check out source]

> I enjoy fairly high health, strong, carry champions with good CC and high kill farm

I will suggest you checking out [**Darius**](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Darius), [Hecarim](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Hecarim), [Renekton](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Renekton), [Singed](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Singed) and [Wukong](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Wukong).

All this champions can carry games especialy first two **Darius** (or *OP-early-and-mid-game-sh%#*) is something most similar IMHO to **Warwick** kit (slow, big damage, pulling-CC skill) but he don't have so much sustain.

**Hecarim** on the other hand if builded ([Spirit Visage](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Spirit_Visage) + [Iceborn Gaunlet](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Iceborn_Gauntlet) FTW!) good way can carry, with his CC and [sustain from his W skill](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Hecarim), in lategame teamfights so hard that enemyes will write *"heca carry"* and *"gg heca"*. That is my personal expiriance :) !

Write if I can help you with other information. Good luck!

Comment: Heca carries becuz of how easy it is for him to gank and counter gank.